# node child_process execSync hangs with xclip

Tags: node.js, child-process, xclip

I'm trying to use `child_process` to execute `xclip -selection c`, but it seems to hang or significantly delay execution.

I've tried using `execSync`,

`require('child_process').execSync('echo hi | xclip -selection c') && console.log('done');`

I've also tried using `exec`,

`require('child_process').exec('echo hi | xclip -selection c', (a) => console.log('done', a)) && undefined;`

In both cases, there is a noticeable delay between pressing `enter` and when `done` is printed. However, the clipboard is actually affected almost immediately, it seems `node` just doesn't seem to realize the command is complete.

Also to note, the delay seems to vary between executions. Plus, the `exec`  variant seems to delay for less time than the `execSync` variant which sometimes seems to hang indefinitely.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question, but I stumbled upon the answer shortly after posting the question.

Apparently `xclip`, by default, doesn't terminate when invoked, but keeps listening for more input. To instruct `xclip` to only expect 1 input requires the `-l` argument, e.g.:

```
require('child_process').execSync('echo hi | xclip -selection c -l') && console.log('done');
```

source: https://github.com/astrand/xclip/issues/45

Comment: No need for apologies, self-answers are welcome on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Since the clipboard is an active protocol there needs to be a process that answers the requests from the X11 server. When you close xclip you lose the clipboard. So xclip needs to be running in the background. Node won't close as long as it has subprocesses that it owns. You must disown them and also you need to close all the streams connecting the node process with them. That being said here is the snippet to do it.

```js
const child_process = require('child_process');
const xclip = child_process.spawn('xclip', ['-se', 'c'], { detached: true, stdio: ['pipe', 'ignore', 'ignore'] });
xclip.stdin.end('copy this');
xclip.unref();
```

The process is unref, stdin is ended, and stdout and seterr are ignored.